# Why does console.log() show an array, but typeof returns 'object'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is relating to the results of a mongoose find() operation. The code

`console.log('apparently this is an ' + typeof campaign.advertGroups, campaign.advertGroups);`

causes the following output:

`apparently this is an object [ { adverts: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] } ]`

`campaign.advertGroups` doesn't act like an array (i.e. the length property is undefined, etc. etc.), even though it's an array within the Mongo collection.

Can anyone shed some light on this? It feels so stupid that I must be missing something very very obvious.

Comment: `typeof`  always returns `"object"` for non-callable non-primitive values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: this was an issue with my Mongoose schema, specifically defining what should have been an array as an object with nested objects. Javascript's technicalities over arrays really being sugarcoated objects muddied the issue, causing console.log and typeof to present seemingly conflicting information; thank you to commenters for that piece of the puzzle!

Answer (score 5):

One of the weird behaviour of javascript is the `typeof []` is an object. Thoug there are ways by which you can check if the object is an array of not.

One of them is:

```
if(Array === someobj.constructor)
{
  console.log('Its an array');
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't consider it "weird", but certainly a nuisance sometimes.  You can also use `Array.isArray`.  Not sure on the support for that in browsers though.

Comment: That does work *except* in cases where the array instance was constructed in another context. This happens when code in an iframe makes a call to code in the parent window. Each window has its own global Array constructor, and they're not equal to each other.

Comment: @Jamen hehe, may be the reasoning for that id my english is not that good. :)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, all. So is there any particular reason why Mongoose is returning what Mongo considers an array as an object? It seems rather counterintuitive.

Comment: @user1381745 All arrays in JavaScript are objects (it's technically just sugarcoat syntax).

Comment: @jamen but it's not _acting_ like an array, in that I can't access the length property, or access the elements via `campaign.advertGroups[0]` (undefined) or similar. That's, essentially, the real problem I'm having.

Comment: @user1381745 That's interesting.

Answer (score 0):

> @jamen but it's not acting like an array, in that I can't access the length property, or access the elements via campaign.advertGroups[0] (undefined) or similar. That's, essentially, the real problem I'm having.

It looks like one strange array.  I'm not sure exactly what the issue is, but you can try calling `.slice` to convert it to a real array:

```
var bar = Array.prototype.slice.call(foo);
```